# Windows Server 2012 VM can't access other 2012 servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, network-share

I have a new Windows Server 2012 DataCenter running on VMWare ESXi 5.1 that can't access shared folders on any other Windows Server 2012. However, this server can ping the servers by hostname and RDP into those other Windows 2012 servers.
I have also checked and others have suggested changing the MTU to 1500 which has been done but that still doesn't fix the issue.
Also, this server can access shares that are on Windows 2008 R2 and below.

At this point I am pretty much at a loss. I have already rebuilt this VM once thinking I had a bad install.

Here is a list of troubleshooting steps I have taken

1. Verify that I can ping the server from the other servers.
2. Verify that I can ping other server from the one having the issue.
3. Attempt to connect to the C$ share from my workstation to the server having the issue
4. Attempt to connect to the C$ share from a Linux server to the server having the issue.

List of Errors that I have found.

1. Event ID 30621 under Server Manager -> File and Storage Services -> Servers -> Events
2. Windows cannot access \ Check the spelling of the name. However I can get to that share from other clients.

Comment: `I have a new Server 2012 DataCenter running on VMWare ESXi 5.1 that can't access shared folders on any other windows server 2012` - Some detail about what happens when you try to access them would be helpful. `I have also checked and others have suggested changing the MTU to 1500 which as been done but that still doesn't fix the issue` - Stop blindly making changes that you read on the internet. Use logic. If the server CAN'T access some shares but CAN access other shares, is the problem likely to be the MTU? No. No it is not.

Comment: Joe thanks for your response. I didn't change the MTU blindly. I changed it based on the recommendation of TechNet which I find to be really helpful. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/03dfeb4e-c725-4d43-a76c-78694251cdb1/server-2012-add-remote-server?forum=winservermanager

Comment: Ensure you have the appropriate permissions on those shares.

Comment: OK, that is not TechNet. That is a TechNet forum. Unless the information is posted by Microsoft in TechNet as a KB then it's just another forum (like this one) where individuals post answers that may or may not be correct. But again, use logic. If the server CAN connect to some shares but CAN'T connect to other shares than the problem is not likely the MTU. Can the other W2K12 servers access other W2K12 shares, including on the server having the problem?

Comment: Thanks slybloty That was the one of the first things I checked. I also found under Server Manager -> File and Storage Services -> Servers -> Events I keep Seeing Event ID 30621 Session to Server <server name> was lost Status 0xC000000C3. Also to answer joeqwerty's question when I try to access just \\servername I get Windows cannot access \\server check the spelling of the name. But again from the command line I can ping the server name by IP.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with more details about what you've done and what you've encountered.

Comment: joeqwerty yes the other 2012 servers can access each other but not the server in question. When I try connecting to \\servername\c$ with my Admin account from my workstation I get The specified server cannot preform the requested operation. However I can connect to the same server in question using linux

Comment: are you able to ping the fqdn of the servers or are you using IP addresses? Possibly a DNS issue?

Comment: Thanks Byron C. Yes I am able to ping. Now here is some new developments. I deleted the Server. Rebuilt the server in our Nashville VM Cluster and I was then able to Access the server shares that I was not able to before. So I shutdown the Server moved it back to my DC datacenter (setup the IP for DC) and problem started all over again. I asked for verification from our Network team and was correct in my thinking that we don't have any firewalls between the MPLS circuits. Plus my all my other virtual servers in DC can access the shares successfully but they are all Server 2008 R2.